# Rake / adapter error during Rails 5 app deploy on Bluemix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, db2, rake, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I'm trying to deploy Rails 5 app with DashDB service on IBM Bluemix platform. According to the logs everything seems to be working fine during the deployment stage until rake command is being triggered:

```
...
OUT    Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 88517c00-d623-43f3-b44b-01e140cba4f6
ERR    rake aborted!
ERR    ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 3..4)
ERR    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:283:in `create_table_definition'
...
```

My manifest.yml looks following:

```
applications:
- path: .
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git
  command: rake db:migrate && bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
  memory: 1024M
  instances: 1
  domain: eu-gb.mybluemix.net
  name: windykacja
  host: windykacja
  disk_quota: 1024M
  services:
  - dashDB-win
```

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
gem "cf-autoconfig", "~> 0.2.1"
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'rack'
gem 'devise'

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'ibm_db'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

..and one last bit of details, database.yml (but I'm not really sure whether it's even being used now):

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  adapter: ibm_db
  database: BLUDB

production:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  adapter: ibm_db
  database: BLUDB
  user: dash105844
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASS'] %>
```

Currently I have only one Environment Variable set up and it's DB_PASS of course. I'm not really sure whether I need more of them (like DATABASE_URL.. which didn't help) - I would appreciate any help from someone experienced with using rails and DashDB / DB2 on Bluemix. I'm fighting with this since few hours and I run out of ideas. Cheers!

EDIT

I've tried to deploy with Rails 4.2.5 and Ruby 2.3.0 but it didn't work either.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :production do
    gem 'rails_12factor'
    gem 'ibm_db'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

manifest.yml:

```
applications:
- path: .
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/ruby-buildpack.git
  command: rake db:migrate && bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
  memory: 1024M
  instances: 1
  domain: eu-gb.mybluemix.net
  name: windykacja
  host: windykacja
  disk_quota: 1024M
  services:
  - dashDB-win
```

errors from the log (please note that IBM messed up and you need to read the logs from the bottom now):

```
DEA/200Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections2016-10-23T12:53:48.857+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:557:in `add_index'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:32:in `create_table'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:925:in `initialize'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:822:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    Tasks: TOP => db:migrate2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `new'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    (See full trace by running task with --trace)2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:1250:in `execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'2016-10-23T12:53:48.715+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:2281:in `execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.714+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:1251:in `block in execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.714+0200
App/0    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL1667N The operation failed because the operation is not supported with the type of the specified table. Specified table: "DASH105844.SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS". Table type: "ORGANIZE BY COLUMN". Operation: "CREATE INDEX". SQLSTATE=42858 SQLCODE=-16672016-10-23T12:53:48.713+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:1250:in `execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:925:in `initialize'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:1251:in `block in execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:2285:in `rescue in execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:32:in `create_table'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `new'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:822:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:2277:in `execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:557:in `add_index'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'2016-10-23T12:53:48.711+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'2016-10-23T12:53:48.710+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'2016-10-23T12:53:48.710+0200
App/0    Failed to execute statement due to: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL1667N The operation failed because the operation is not supported with the type of the specified table. Specified table: "DASH105844.SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS". Table type: "ORGANIZE BY COLUMN". Operation: "CREATE INDEX". SQLSTATE=42858 SQLCODE=-16672016-10-23T12:53:48.710+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'2016-10-23T12:53:48.710+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `new'2016-10-23T12:53:48.710+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'2016-10-23T12:53:48.710+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:925:in `initialize'2016-10-23T12:53:48.710+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:822:in `initialize_schema_migrations_table'2016-10-23T12:53:48.710+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:2277:in `execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:1251:in `block in execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/schema_migration.rb:32:in `create_table'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:557:in `add_index'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:2285:in `rescue in execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: RuntimeError: Failed to execute statement due to: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL1667N The operation failed because the operation is not supported with the type of the specified table. Specified table: "DASH105844.SCHEMA_MIGRATIONS". Table type: "ORGANIZE BY COLUMN". Operation: "CREATE INDEX". SQLSTATE=42858 SQLCODE=-1667: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_schema_migrations ON schema_migrations (version)2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    /home/vcap/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ibm_db-3.0.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/ibm_db_adapter.rb:1250:in `execute'2016-10-23T12:53:48.709+0200
App/0    rake aborted!2016-10-23T12:53:48.708+0200
App/0     [1m[35m (13.8ms)[0m CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_schema_migrations ON schema_migrations (version)2016-10-23T12:53:48.706+0200
App/0     [1m[36m (363.7ms)[0m [1mCREATE TABLE schema_migrations (version varchar(255) NOT NULL) [0m2016-10-23T12:53:48.457+0200
DEA/200  Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 8b29e93c-2560-4396-8fb0-354041aa69d52016-10-23T12:53:33.764+0200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ibm_db` Rails Adapater does not yet support Rails 5.

Comment: I've tried the same settings on Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.2 - didn't work either.

Comment: The `rake` error you're showing occurs because Rails 5 isn't supported yet.  Perhaps post the errors you get with Rails 4.2?

Comment: I've just edited my question with Rails 4.2.5 setup and error messages from the server logs.

Comment: One more thing - I've just found that removing command line from manifest.yml did allow to successfully build & deploy the app.. and it looks like it's working fine. It's not crashing anymore and DB is being updated!

Comment: One last comment:  You should be aware that dashDB is really intended for analytic, not transactional, environments. The default is for tables to be created in columnar format, which has performance implications for transactional applications. If your Rails application will be doing a lot of update/delete operations you may run into performance issues as data volume increases.  

You may can avoid this if you can (re)create the tables yourself by specifying `ORGANIZE BY ROW` instead of `ORGANIZE BY COLUMN`, which is how they are likely currently created.